# ack-grep Regex not returning consistent results

Tags: regex, grep, ack

I am preforming the following `ack-grep` inside of a `bash` script and, while it *mostly* works .. I am getting inconsistent results.  The line I am using is:

`ack-grep '(?<=imageserver).*(?=png)'`

This is Perl type Regex (supported by both `ack_grep` and plain `grep`) -- I am searching for everything between `imageserver` and `png`.  While it *mostly* works --  I get inconsistent results IE:

[image: ack-grep results]

Why is it that you'll see it matched the first umpteen lines, then it matches something that it (in theory) should have two or three matches WITHIN.  It's obvious the last "block" *should* have been matched after the **first** iteration of `png` however it skipped it multiple times and finally settled --

So, the first couple returning are my desired result --  And the last highlighted block is the "bad" result.  How do I get consistent results here?  I'll paste some text that returns this result for copy/paste posterity (verifiable example).   If you copy and paste the following into a text file, you should get the same results I am getting.

Is this a syntax error, a misunderstanding, or a bug?  Hate when things *should* work but don't ...  The banes of development.

```
.mobile_menu_icon { display:block;cursor:pointer;width:100%;height:40px;margin:0 auto;background-image:url('/imageserver/default_images/four_lines_40x19.png');
.button-error { display:inline-block;width:14px;height:13px;background:url('/imageserver/GlobalMedia/Icons/deleteIcon.png') no-repeat;background-size:16px 16px;background-position:center;opacity:1;transition:all ease-in-out 150ms; }
.button-finished { display:inline-block;width:14px;height:13px;background:url('/imageserver/GlobalMedia/Icons/checkmark.png') no-repeat;background-size:16px 16px;background-position:center; }
background:url('/imageserver/confirm/ie.png');
background:url('/imageserver/confirm/buttons.png') no-repeat;
background:url('/imageserver/confirm/buttons.png') no-repeat;
.capItem { width:30px;height:30px;background:url('/imageserver/styles/captchaShapesWhite.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto 35px;display:inline-block;margin:0 3px; }
.form_button_error { display:inline-block;width:14px;height:13px;background:url('/imageserver/GlobalMedia/Icons/deleteIcon.png') no-repeat;background-size:13px 13px;background-position:center;opacity:1;transition:all ease-in-out 150ms; }
.form_button_finished { display:inline-block;width:14px;height:13px;background:url('/imageserver/GlobalMedia/Icons/checkmark.png') no-repeat;background-size:16px 16px;background-position:center; }
#mega_slider_wrapper,.shadow{width:100%;position:relative}.nav-arrows,.nav-dots,.shadow{display:none}.nav-arrows a,.nav-dots span,.nav-options span{cursor:pointer;border-radius:50%}#mega_slider_wrapper{background:0 0;overflow:hidden}#mega_slider_wrapper img,.mega_slide_image{width:100%}.shadow{height:168px;margin-top:-110px;background:url(/imageserver/AdminMedia/moduleImages/megaslider/shadow.png) bottom center no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;z-index:-1}.sb-description h3{text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3)}.sb-description h3 a{color:#4a3c27;text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5)}.nav-arrows a{width:42px;height:42px;background:url(/imageserver/AdminMedia/moduleImages/megaslider/nav.png) top left no-repeat #cbbfae;position:absolute;top:50%;left:2px;text-indent:-9000px;opacity:.9;box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.8)}.nav-arrows a:first-child{left:auto;right:2px;background-position:top right}.nav-arrows a:hover{opacity:1}.nav-dots{text-align:center;position:absolute;height:30px;width:100%;left:0}.nav-dots span{display:inline-block;width:16px;height:16px;margin:3px;box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.6),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.nav-dots span.nav-dot-current{box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.6),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 0 0 3px #cbbfae,inset 0 0 0 8px #fff}.nav-options{width:70px;height:30px;position:absolute;right:70px;bottom:0;display:none}.nav-options span{width:30px;height:30px;background:url(/imageserver/AdminMedia/moduleImages/megaslider/options.png) top left no-repeat #cbbfae;text-indent:-9000px;opacity:.7;display:inline-block}.sb-slider,.sb-slider li>img{width:100%}.nav-options span:first-child{background-position:-30px 0;margin-right:3px}.nav-options span:hover{opacity:1}.sb-slider{margin:0 auto;position:relative;overflow:hidden;list-style-type:none;padding:0;max-width:2000px!important}.sb-slider li{margin:0;padding:0;display:none}.sb-slider li>a{outline:0}.sb-slider img{max-width:100%;display:block}.sb-description{width:100%;max-width:1124px;margin:0 auto;padding:30px 10px 10px;height:900px;top:0;left:10px;right:10px;z-index:10;position:absolute;color:#fff;-webkit-transition:all .2s;-moz-transition:all .2s;-o-transition:all .2s;-ms-transition:all .2s;transition:all .2s;background:rgba(40,40,40,.2);text-shadow:#000 0 0 7px}.sb-description h2,.sb-description h3{line-height:1.1;margin:4px 0;padding:4px 0}.nav-dots span,.slider_button{transition:all ease-in-out 180ms}.sb-description h2{font-size:42px}.sb-description h3{font-size:22px}.sb-perspective{position:relative}.sb-perspective>div{position:absolute;-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;-moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;-o-transform-style:preserve-3d;-ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;transform-style:preserve-3d;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;-o-backface-visibility:hidden;-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;backface-visibility:hidden}.sb-side{margin:0;display:block;position:absolute;-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;-moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;-o-transform-style:preserve-3d;-ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;transform-style:preserve-3d}.nav-arrows,.nav-arrows a,.nav-dots{z-index:11!important}.nav-arrows a{margin-top:-60px!important;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px}.nav-dots{bottom:0!important;background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);padding:8px}.nav-dots span{background:#777}.nav-dots span:hover{background:#aaa}.slider_button{position:relative;display:inline-block;line-height:1;width:auto;padding:10px 16px;background:#1F1E1E;border-radius:5px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;margin:12px 0 0;font-size:16px}.slider_button:hover{background:#333}@media (max-width:1170px){.sb-description{width:85%!important;min-width:auto!important;margin:0 60px;box-sizing:border-box}}@media (max-width:850px){.sb-description{width:80%!important;min-width:auto!important;margin:0 60px;box-sizing:border-box}.sb-description h2,.sb-description h3{line-height:1.1;margin:4px 0;padding:4px 0}.sb-description h2{font-size:28px}.sb-description h3{font-size:14px}}@media (max-width:650px){.sb-description{width:75%!important;min-width:auto!important;margin:0 60px;box-sizing:border-box}}@media (max-width:600px){.hide_in_mobile{display:none}}
<div class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/imageserver/UserMedia/zakattack/Logo.png" /></a></div>
<div class="mobile_logo"><a href="/"><img src="/imageserver/UserMedia/zakattack/mobile.png" alt="Logo" /></a></div>
<div class="powered_by">Powered by <a href="http://yourwebpro.com" target="new"><img src="/imageserver/UserMedia/ywpgallery/ywpLogo.png" style="max-height:25px;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Your Web Pro | Roofing and Contractor Websites" title="On-Line Showrooms for Roofers & Contractors"></a></div>
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, thanks for your reply ..  I explained in my OP that the first few "returns" you see in the image are correct --  and the last "block" is incorrect.  So that is my desired output. The input, or file to search through, I have included as well -- So others may simply copy and paste to create a file,  and run the single line of code that is giving me issues ..  I'll gladly add to the post, however I literally have posted everything I have .. The "bad" line of code .. The "desired" outcome and the "weird (unexpected)" outcome .. What am I missing?

Comment: To further .. in the image .. Lines `63`, `186` and `188` are all correct ..  Line `1841` is the "strange' result.

Comment: Which I may have answered my own question .. Is this a "per line" problem?  Simply returning everything between the **first** `imageserver` and the **last** `png` on a entire line rather than separating them?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is a per line issue. The `.*` matches everthing from the first "imageserver" to the last "png".

Comment: OK .. Great .. Is there a "better" way of grabbing **every occurrence**  between `imageserver` and `png` regardless of having the possibility of multiple occurrences on a single line?  I am looking into `sed` right now ..

Comment: Can't you just make the regex non greedy? In the example (https://regex101.com/r/FvSwg4/1) it should return all desired matches or?

Comment: @gaw -- I can, and did -- That's an acceptable alternative.  If you post an answer, with an explanation of "non greedy" and how the regex you posted works, for future readers, I'll gladly accept it.  thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your version of the regex is that it is greedy, which means `.*` consumes all characters until the end of the line and performs a backtracking then. That's why in your broken part (the long yellow line) the expression matches everything between 'imageserver' and the **last** 'png'.

A slight modification can make your regex non-greedy; just add a `?` after the quantifier. Then the new regex will also search for a preceding 'imageserver' but it directly checks for each following character if a 'png' sequence is following. So, it only consumes and matches the text until the **first** 'png' sequence.
The example with the new regex `(?<=imageserver).*?(?=png)` and your text can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/FvSwg4/1

It is also a good idea to have a look at the regex-debugger view for the example. Then one can better understand the single steps that have to be performed for the matching.